# Finding the expectation value of a mixed function of both momenta and coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, foundations

I'm reading Merzbacher's *Quantum mechanics*. In Chapter 3, section 2, he tackles this question. For a function solely of coordinates, say $f(\mathbf r)$, he says that the expectation value is given by
$$\langle f(\mathbf r)\rangle = \int\psi^*(\mathbf r, t)\; f(\mathbf r)\;\psi(\mathbf r, t)\;d^3r, $$
and this makes sense to me.

But for a function like $f(x, k_y, z)$, he first defines
$$\chi(x, k_y, z, t):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\psi(\mathbf{r}, t)\; e^{-ik_yy}\; dy,$$
and says that $|\chi(x, k_y, y, t)|^2$ "can easily be seen to be the probability density of finding the particle to have coordinates $x$ and $z$, but indeterminate $y$, whereas the $y$-component of it's momentum [wavenumber]$^1$ is $p_y$ [$k_y$]."

I do observe that
$$\int |\chi(x ,k_y, z)|^2\;dx\;dk_y\;dz = 1,$$
but even so, I fail to see that it should be the probability density that Merzbacher quotes.

**Question:** Is this—that $|\chi|^2$ is the required probability—an assumption (a postulate)? Or does it, as Merzbacher seem to claim, follow from some probability considerations?

---

$^1$ Merzbacher does this for momentum, $p_y$, but I find it better to talk of $k_y$. $p_y=\hbar k_y$ switches back and forth between these equivalent formulations.

Answer (score 0):

Given a state $|\psi\rangle$, the probability to find the system in another state $|\phi\rangle $ is of course $|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2$. Therefore, the probability to find a particle at position $x$ and $z$ (in the $x$ and $z$ directions) and with momentum $p_y$ in the $y$ direction is the projection onto the state $|x,p_y,z\rangle$, which gives $\chi(x,p_y,z)$ of the OP.

Note that we can define this mixed (in momentum and position) probability because the observables $X,Z$ and $P_y$ are compatible, i.e. we can diagonalize them simultaneously.

Comment: Merzbacher is yet to postulate this $|\langle \phi | \psi \rangle|^2$ postulate. So I think this should be justified by some other means.

Comment: This is pretty much one of the postulates of quantum mechanics...

Comment: I was hoping that Merzbacher would be precise in formulating his assumptions, but alas...

Comment: Never opened this book, but I would be surprised if the postulates of QM are not discussed before that... Maybe you have not understood that as well as you thought?

Comment: You know some better precise book for this? I am not so mathematically advanced to read Hall's book for mathematicians though. So I'm looking for some physics book, but precise.

Comment: I like Cohen-Tannoudji's book, starting from chapter 2